# Problem with \label and \ref in TexMaker

Tags: cross-referencing

I've got a problem using `\label` and `\ref` in Texmaker 3.1 (MiKTeX 2.9). When I put label somewhere, i got a frame with label name in it. How can I hide it?

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{img/2}\caption{SomeCaption}
\label{fig:4eb1}
\end{figure}
$\frac{w}{w_1}-1=4$ $4\leqslant n\leqslant3$, using (pic. \ref{fig:4eb1}),blah-blah.
```

PS: Sorry for my awesome English. :)

---

[image]

Comment: A proper [minimal example](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl) would have been nice that shows exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probably loading the [showkeys](http://ctan.org/pkg/showkeys) package somewhere in your document preamble. Just drop it and the problem will vanish.

Comment: Good use of the old 'crystal ball' :-)

Comment: @JosephWright: Yeah, sometimes it seems to work. So, don't put it away.